# Hover Drop Down With Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

So I have this dropdown menu, when you hover over a link a dropdown menu pops up with overflow as auto. My problem is that as soon as I put my mouse over the bottom link or try to scroll it, the hover stops and the block disappears like its reached its height limit. It does this in Chrome and Firefox but works sorta fine in IE8. Suggestions on what I can do to fix this? Here's my code:

CSS

```
*{margin:0px; padding:0px}
#container{background-color:pink;padding:30px;width:300px;}
#dropMenu{display: none;
     height: 75px;
     overflow: auto;
     width: 200px;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" onMouseOver="menuOpen()">Hover This</a>
    <div id="dropMenu">
        <a href="#">Menu Item1</a><br />
        <a href="#">Menu Item2</a><br />
        <a href="#">Menu Item3</a><br />
        <a href="#">Menu Item4</a><br />
        <a href="#">Menu Item5</a><br />
        <a href="#">Menu Item6</a><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function menuOpen(){
        document.getElementById('dropMenu').style.display = 'block';
    }

    document.getElementById('dropMenu').onmouseout = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.srcElement||e.target;
        if (target.id == "dropMenu") {
            document.getElementById('dropMenu').style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
</script>
```

Before I get questions, assume my CSS is in my header in the right style tags, divs are in the body and script is before the ending body tag.

Comment: I didn't really want to import the entire library for a single hover effect. Small things like that I find JS to be easier IMO

Comment: Fair enough, if it's just this one event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind that the menu drops down when you hover over the pink container instead of just the link, you can use this CSS-only solution:

```
*{margin:0px; padding:0px}

#container{background-color:pink;padding:30px;width:300px;}

#dropMenu{display: none;
  height: 75px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;}

#container:hover #dropMenu {
  display:block;
}
```

No JavaScript needed. It's cleaner and works better. Have a look at my example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRgNW/).

Comment: Thanks, I probably should have specified in my question. Really this is going into a sidebar with each container being a class. :S sorry

Comment: But what's stopping you from having a `:hover` rule for every container?

Comment: if I put a `.container:hover` and have 3 container classes, then no matter what container they hover the menu will pop up right? And I can't make it the first child either because other things need to go on top of it. `nth` child isn't supported in every browser yet either sadly :(

Comment: Huh sorry I'm not following you. Could you show the problem you think you will experience using jsFiddle?

Comment: hmmmmmm I figured if I added a "classname:hover ID{}" and had multiple classnames, then no matter what classname you hovered it would activate the action. I guess it only activates it if `#dropmenu` is inside that class right?

Comment: It works like `#container-you-hover-over:hover #thing-you-want-to-expand { display: block; }`